# How to multithread effectively

Tags: java, multithreading, architecture

I'm writing an asynchronous program and I have two choices:

A) Run the threads on one core and lose the parallel processing advantage

B) Run the threads on different cores and have have potential latency issues (cores have to communicate with each other)

What is the better option? Am I better off not worrying about it and letting the os decide, or can I get more performance by going with an option above?

Comment: Holy moly, what's with the same questions today. It is impossible to give a good general answer, because it changes from problem to problem, and even from instance to instance of the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) if you have blocking operations, you don't necessarily lose parallelism. You did say "asynchronous," though, so you might not be blocking. Thread schedulers will schedule other threads to run when one is blocking.

B) this is all moot; Java doesn't have thread affinity, so you don't even get a choice. The OS gets to choose which cores it uses. Latency when you communicate between threads is low--maybe 100ns at most. This is really only an issue of the threads are communicating with each other a lot.

It sounds like what you really want to know is can you still see a performance benefit from multiple threads with asynchronous operations. Yes, you can.

All of that said, you should read up on more on concurrency patterns and Java. If you implement A or B incorrectly, performance can be horrible, so you need a deep understanding of what's going on if you want to avoid the major gotcahs. *Java Concurrency in Practice* is a good read for things like this.